# Deleting records using delete/where exists problem

Tags: sql, mysql

My problem is I want to delete records from two tables, deleting the records that are a result of the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(pr.rating) AS rating_average
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_ratings pr 
ON pr.product_id = p.product_id  
GROUP BY p.product_id 
HAVING AVG(pr.rating) < 3
```

The above query shows average ratings of a product that are less than 3, I want to delete products and their associated ratings of all the results from the above query.

I looked at `DELETE FROM product_ratings, products WHERE EXISTS (//above query)`, but this didn't work, I've been trying various DELETE statements to no avail.

I have read the following, and still cannot find a solution: [SQL: DELETE Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/delete.php) & [SQL: EXISTS Condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php).

The tables are `products` and `product_ratings`, with the following structure:

```
products
--------
product_id [PK] | link | ...

product_ratings
---------------
rating_id [PK] | rating | product_id
```

Appreciate any help, as well as links to reference material to better understand how it's done.

EDIT: Apologies for not stating what RDBMS I'm using, It's MySQL

EDIT2: A bit confused now, @Martin's example doesn't use a temp table like the other answers, I assume this is because of my vague question not stating with RDBMS I was using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have now added the `MySQL` tag. In that case this might do the job for you.

```
DELETE products,
       product_ratings
FROM   products,
       product_ratings
WHERE  product_ratings.product_id = products.product_id
       AND product_ratings.product_id IN 
 (SELECT product_id
        FROM   (SELECT p.product_id
                FROM   products p
                       LEFT JOIN product_ratings pr
                         ON pr.product_id = p.product_id
                GROUP  BY p.product_id
                HAVING COALESCE(AVG(pr.rating), 0) < 3) T)
```

[MySQL **does** support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) a multiple table DELETE syntax. The derived table is to get around the issue where it doesn't allow mutating (update or delete target) tables to be referenced in a sub query ([it materializes the result into a temporary table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)).

Comment: Sorry Martin, I went AFK, this works as I need, however, is there a way to extend the `HAVING AVG(rating) < 3`, so that it deletes if there is a rating doesn't exist at all? Pseudo code would be: `HAVING AVG(rating) < 3 or doesn't exist`

Comment: @Daniel - I have amended the sub query to do this. Test it first as I haven't executed this code at all...

Comment: Doesn't delete anything `0 row(s) deleted. ( Query took 0.0025 sec )`

Comment: @Daniel - I guess the outer query needs to have an `OUTER JOIN` as well actually in order to not exclude those products that do not have a rating. Have all the ones with `AVG(pr.rating) < 3` been deleted already because I can't see why they wouldn't have been deleted?

Comment: Yes, the original query worked fine, and deleted everything, which is why when you changed it and I ran that, it deleted nothing. Thanks anyway, I will just write a seperate query to remove products from DB that don't have an associated rating, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a foriegn key with a referential constraint between the tables.

You can make it do a cascading delete automatically (when a parent record is deleted, the child records will be automatically deleted).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE

Answer (score 1):

Add the `p.product_id` to your select statement and store the results of that query in a temporary table. Then use that temporary table to delete from `product_ratings` and `products` in two separate delete operations.

The specific syntax of the delete will depend on which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports it, you could add a foreign key-constraint with an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause to the `product_ratings` table, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE product_ratings ADD CONSTRAINT fk_prodratings_prods 
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Once you've added this constraint, you only need to `DELETE` from the `products` table.  The `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint on the constraint above will then delete the ratings for you, e.g.

```
DELETE FROM products p 
 WHERE (SELECT AVG(pr.rating)
          FROM product_ratings pr
         WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id) < 3;
```